# HTMLunit (HtmlImage) java.io.IOException: No image detected in response

Tags: java, web, htmlunit

i Try to save a picture from a website, normal is this working perfect:

```
 final HtmlImage im = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='picture']/img");

        File imageFile = new File(pictureFile);
        im.saveAs(imageFile);
```

now on this webseite he tell me: java.io.IOException: No image detected in response

The webseite code is:

```
<div class="picture">

<img border="0" src="/e/s?random=0.9705617034141113"></img>
```

someone has a idea?

edit:

i found thats he give me on

```
 final HtmlImage im = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='picture']/img");
```

only `<img border="0"/>`

why o.O